# Check if localStorage equals value, hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my second question so i hope it addresses everything. I dont know alot of javascript and therefore cant exactly make my code work. I tried many different codes but could not fix it. Everything in brackets is what i want but cannot make work. I want this to happen in summary:

### -if button 1 is pressed:Set localStorage.thing1 to 0

### -if button 2 is pressed:Set localStorage.thing1 to 1

### -if localStorage.thing1 == 0, Hide thingtext1. else, show thingtext1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="thingtext1">Here Is Some Text</p>
<button id="thing1" onclick="(set value of thing1 to 0 to localStorage)">Hide</button>
<button id="thing1" onclick="(set value of thing1 to 1 to localStorage)">Show</button>

<script>
(ONLOAD)
if (localStorage.getItem("thing1") === "0") {
(HIDE(#thingtext1))
}
else{
if (localStorage.getItem("thing1") === "1"){
(SHOW(#thingtext1))
}
}
(SET thing1 to localStorage)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you could please help me. 
Thankyou.

Comment: Try searching the internet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: i know how to get and set localStorage items but i dont know how to use the if statement correctly

Comment: im new to code so please dont hate my question too much

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
<p id="thingtext1">Here Is Some Text</p>
<button id="thing1" onClick="localStorage.setItem('thing1', '0')">Hide</button>
<button id="thing1" onClick="localStorage.setItem('thing1', '1')">Show</button>

<script>
    $(function () {
      $(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("thing1") == "0") {
            $("#thingtext1").hide();
        }else if (localStorage.getItem("thing1") == "1"){
            $("#thingtext1").show();
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Here,

```
$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
```

will execute on LocalStorage's change in value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="thingtext1">Here Is Some Text</p>
<button id="thing1" onclick="storeLS('0')">Hide</button>
<button id="thing1" onclick="storeLS('1')">Show</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function storeLS(num){
        localStorage.setItem("thing1", num);
        showRhide();
    }

    function showRhide(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("thing1") == "0") {
            $("#thingtext1").hide();
        }else if (localStorage.getItem("thing1") == "1"){
            $("#thingtext1").show();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        showRhide();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work :(
<p id="thingtext1">hi</p>
<button id="thing1" onclick="storeLS('0')">Hide</button>
<button id="thing1" onclick="storeLS('1')">Show</button>

<script>
function storeLS(num){
    localStorage.setItem("thing1", num);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
d
    if (localStorage.getItem("thing1") == "0") {
        $("#thingtext1").hide();
    }else if (localStorage.getItem("thing1") == "1"){
        $("#thingtext1").show();
    }

});
</script>
'LINKED JQUERY 3.0.0 SCRIPT'

Comment: It works great! but after refreshing the page the element went back to default (show). If you could make the localStorage save the state of the item... Shown or Hidden. That would be great! thanks

Comment: look at the $(document).ready function.  I included "showRhide()"

Comment: Thank you for all the help but i dont think i know enough code to get it to work. I am only familiar with HTML5 and CSS3. The show and hide works but when i reload localStorage is undefined. Ive been linking it to this:   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>...

Comment: `$("#thingtext1").toggle(localStorage.getItem("thing1") == "1");`